# Subtraction of Date in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, date, subtraction

I want to subtract two dates in angularjs which are getting fetched from database. The code works fine for all values except subtraction between dates fetching from database...I used PHP with MySQL
can anyone tell me how to do this subtraction. Here is the code. Thanx in advance

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app= angular.module("myapp",[]);
                        app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope,$http){
                        $http.get("select.php").success(function(response)
                         {
                            $scope.names = response.data.records;});

                        });

    </script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myapp"   ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>ID </th>
            <th>Name of employee</th>
            <th>Start Date </th>
            <th>End Date </th>
            <th>No of days Worked </th>

        </tr>
        <tr  ng-repeat="emp in names">
            <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.stDate}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.enDate}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.stDate-emp.enDate}}</td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write a controller function, that do all calculation and return the reuslt.

```
$scope.calDate = function(date1, date2){
   var dateOut1 = new Date(date1); // it will work if date1 is in ISO format
   var dateOut2 = new Date(date2);
   var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOut2.getTime() - dateOut1.getTime());
   var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
   return diffDays;
};
```

and in HTML

```
<tr  ng-repeat="emp in names">
            <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.stDate}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.enDate}}</td>
            <td>{{calDate(emp.stDate,emp.endDate)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It shows "TypeError: date2.getTime is not a function" this error

Comment: it should be var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOut2.getTime() - dateOut1.getTime());

Comment: I have one more doubt, i want to subtract current date from end date so how should i do it?

Comment: just do  var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOut2.getTime() -  new Date().getTime());

Comment: How should i write new Date in ng repeat?

Comment: you need to write inside the controller.

Comment: i wrote it in controller but how to use in ng-repeat

Comment: sorry missed your comment, you cant pass inside your function, instead you can do it inside the method as i shown above